# Volume of a divisor on a smooth projective surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, divisors

Let $X$ be a  smooth projective surface (over complex numbers). Let $D$ be a divisor on $X$. Then we know that its volume is defined as $$\text{vol}_X(D):= \lim \sup_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{h^0(X, \mathcal O_X(mD))}{{m^2}/2}.$$

Suppose that, for a divisor $D$ on $X$, it is known that $\text{vol}_X(D)=D^2$, where $D^2$ stands for its self-intersection number.

> **Question.** What does this signify algebro-geometrically? And what are some interesting properties of $D$ that one can deduce
> once the volume is explicitly known?

Comment: Well, $D$ nef surely implies your condition (by asymptotic Riemann-Roch).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi, yes that's true. But here the situation is the converse question. And more importantly what can we say about the divisor by looking at the value of it's volume? I mean is there  any classification result in the literature in terms of the volume ( or anything partially close to that?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least for *effective* divisors, the answer is strongly related to *Zariski decomposition*.

If $D$ is an effective divisor on a smooth surface $X$, Zariski proved in **[Z62]** that there exists a unique decomposition $D=P + N$, where

- $P$ is a nef $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor
- $N$ is an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor
- $PC=0$ for every curve $C$ appearing in $\operatorname{Supp}(N)$
- if $N \neq 0$ and $\operatorname{Supp}(N)=C_1 \cup \ldots \cup C_k$, then the intersection form $I(C_1, \ldots, C_k)$ is negative defined.

Furthermore, one also shows that, for all positive integers $m$, the natural map $$H^0(X,  \left \lfloor{mP}\right \rfloor) \to H^0(X, \, mD) $$ is an isomorphism. This means that "$P$ carries all sections of $D$" and so $$\operatorname{vol}_X(D)=\operatorname{vol}_X(P)= P^2,$$ where the last equality is a consequence of the asymptotic form of Riemann-Roch theorem, because $P$ is nef.

Thus, $\operatorname{vol}_X(D)=D^2$ is equivalent to $D^2=P^2$; since $PN=0$, this happens if and only if $N^2=0$. But the intersection form must be negative defined on $N$ when $N \neq 0$, hence the only possibility is $N=0$, namely, $D=P$.

Summing up:

> given an effective divisor $D$ on a smooth surface $X$, we have
> $\operatorname{vol}_X(D)=D^2$ if and only if $D$ is nef.

More generally, the difference $$D^2-\operatorname{vol}_X(D)$$ equals the self-intersection $N^2$ of the negative part of the Zariski decomposition of $D$, so it can be seen as a measure of how much "$D$ fails to be nef".

**References.**

**[Z62]** O. Zariski [The theorem of Riemann-Roch for high multiples of an effective divisor on an algebraic surface](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970376), *Ann. Math.* (2) **76**, 560-615 (1962). [ZBL0124.37001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0124.37001).

Comment: Do you mean $D$ is $\mathbb Q$-nef or just nef?(please correct me if one implies the other)

Comment: nef is a numerical property, so I would not use the expression "$\mathbb{Q}$-nef". If you start with an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor $D$, then the argument above simply shows that $D^2=\text{vol}(D)$ if and only if $D$ is a nef $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor.

Comment: Does the same classification hold for the case when $D$ is just an effective divisor (not necessarily $\mathbb Q$-effective)?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you start with an integral effective divisor $D$, the argument above shows that $D^2=\mathrm{vol}(D)$ if and only if $D=P$, so $D$ is an integral nef divisor.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and the clarifications.

Comment: if we remove 'integral' condition from the assumption, will the same classification  still hold?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your last question. Zariski's decomposition holds for $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors, so the general statement is (as I said before) "If an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor $D$ is such that $\text{vol}(D)=D^2$, then $D$ is nef". The case where $D$ is effective and integral is a particular case of this.

Comment: what I meant was that : Perhaps we don't need to assume either irreducibility or reducedness  of the divisor $D$ right? by integral divisor  you mean the divisor that we use in everyday algebraic geometry (with integer coeffecients) right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh yes, by "integral" divisor, in this context,  I meant a divisor with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Sorry for the ambiguity.